# Correct regex for param after an optional forward slash

Tags: php, regex, phalcon, phalcon-routing

What is the correct way on PHP, Phalcon Framework on how to optionally escape a forward slash "**/**" that has optional parameter at the end.

**I want to achieve:**

```
http://example.com/transactions
http://example.com/transactions/
http://example.com/transactions/1
http://example.com/transactions/2
```

**My regex:**

Working, but without params :(

```
transactions[/]{0,1}
```

Not working, on server logs, it's adding "transactions/2" even if the url does not have it.

```
transactions[/]{0,1}{param}
```

**Working, but explicitly instruct to have a param at the end. How can I have an optional "**/**" forward slash.**

```
transactions/{param}
```

Appreciate any advise.

Thanks

Comment: In Phalcon do you specify the delimiter?

Comment: The author "Phalcon" on the forum suggested on a similar note to just use two routes one with param, the other does not have it. https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/2823/optional-param-in-phalcon-router#C24517

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a TransactionsController with an indexAction(), try **defining two routes** like explained :

```
<?php
$router->add(
    "/transactions/{param}",
    array(
        "controller" => "transactions",
        "action"     => "index",
    )
);

$router->add(
    "/transactions",
    array(
        "controller" => "transactions",
        "action"     => "index",
    )
);
```